# Can Value Objects create their own value?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, php, domain-driven-design, value-object

Let's say you have a username value object which has formatting rules e.g.,

```
class Username
{
    private $username; 

    public function __construct(string $username)
    {
        // thrown an exception if invalid regex ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
        // ...

        $this->username = $username;
    }
}
```

Like above, usually you would pass the raw string from "outside" to validate the username.

My question is, can value objects have "additional functionality" like generate its own value, like for example, generate a username? e.g.,

```
class Username
{
    private $username; 

    // original __constuct() remains here
    // ...

    public function generateUsername(UserRepository $userRepository): self
    {
        $username = $this->generateRandomUsername();

        if (!$userRepository->userExist($username))           
             return new self($username);
    }
}
```

The example is just a quick pseudocode of the idea but the idea is `generateUsername()` would take `UserRepository` to validate if the newly generated username from within the class does not exist yet in the database.

Can value objects have a functionally like this, or should they behave more like the first example, where they just accept and validate input from the "outside"?

Comment: Why is this considered a "value object?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm still grasping the whole idea but I think `Username` is a value object for me and it belongs to a  `User` entity.

Comment: I don't know, this seems like a lot of complexity for not a lot of benefit.  A user name is simply a field in a database.  It is an "attribute" of a user.  From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object): *"a value object is a small object that represents a simple entity whose equality is not based on identity: i.e. two value objects are equal when they have the same value, not necessarily being the same object."

Comment: The only two benefits I've been able to find for them is that they are small (and therefore easily copied), and can be "reused."  The typical example given is an address (which can be "reused" as a work address or a home address), but addresses are too large to be good examples.  Normally one would identify addresses with an ID of some sort, not the entire address.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Indeed value objects can be overkill but I also like them for now at least. They seem to provide "integrity" all throughout the app once they are created. So I guess that answer to the question is they aren't suppose to generate their own value?

Comment: Well, what I would consider a "value object" is something like a User ID, not a user name.  User ID's can be system generated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP. Do you need to already have a Username in order to call this function? Do you need to do `new Username("dummy")->generateUsername($repo)` or can you do `Username::generateUsername($repo)`? The first one is obviously flawed.

Comment: @user253751 Indeed. The syntax the OP provided is incorrect. It should be `public _static_ function`. This allows for invocation like your second snippet.

Comment: Well, if the function is static, then the value object is *not* "creating its own value". The static function is creating a value and the static function is not part of an object.

Comment: @user253751 That is correct, but with one caveat: Defining static factory methods on the object they are constructing is _usually_ the best approach. Not only because it is simpler, but also because it allows for such methods to work with members declared `private` on the object. This can help with encapsulation at the expense of the portability of the factory method. So in a way, it _is_ kinda sorta creating its own value when you look at it in that light. To be clear, the above is not an endorsement of the OP's approach. Just a general statement about factory methods.

Comment: @king-side-slide Static methods aren't really defined on objects. They're defined on classes.

Comment: @user253751 I think you know what OP means. Whether they used the right words is unimportant.

Comment: @king-side-slide of course words are important. You can't just mix them up willy-nilly. "Is it good for houses to create their own plans?" "What?" "I think you know what the question means: is it good for people to plan their own houses? Whether it used the right words is unimportant."

Comment: @user253751 Why are we doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Value Objects create their own value?

Yes, it's not unusual to do that, especially with compound values that need to be backwards compatible with earlier models.

```
public function generateUsername(UserRepository $userRepository): self
{
    $username = $this->generateRandomUsername();

    if (!$userRepository->userExist($username))           
         return new self($username);
}
```

That's a bit weird.  Most notably because we don't normally pass repositories to the domain model, and because random numbers are usually an input (like time).

Furthermore, *uniqueness* is a specialized case of "set validation".  In the case where your repository is backed by an relational database, you may be able to manage, but in the general case trying to enforce uniqueness other than of the key used to lookup the aggregate gets complicated.